# Building an application with offline satellite maps

Tags: android, geolocation, maps, geospatial, google-maps-api-2

I'm looking to build an Android application that makes use of a mapping API to display satellite maps offline.
 Obviously I can't store the whole map of the world because its too much data to store, so my idea is to be able to put satellite maps of different countries onto different SD cards and then the users selects the SD card with the map of the country they would like and puts it in the phone where the map will then be displayed in my app.
Preferably I'd like to avoid using Google maps.

So my question is what API's for Android are out there that would allow me to build an application that can show satellite view maps that can be stored on an SD card for offline use?
 
thanks

Comment: One cheat of offline loading is simply display the area of the map once because the google map api v2 will buffer the images.

Comment: Esri (ArcGIS) has offline map capabilities with their tiled package (*.tpk) maps.

Comment: Yeah I've just started looking into ArcGIS actuallly, I've emailed them to see if their API would be suitable for my application